# Frame issue in Adobe LiveCycle Workspace with IE8/XP/Reader 9.4

Tags: internet-explorer-8, workspace, livecycle, adobe-reader

When a user opens a form in Workspace, it renders in a separate frame, instead of in the normal position in the UI.  This frame cannot be repositioned and obscures/blocks the user action buttons, preventing the user from continuing the process.  No issue with IE7/XP/any version of Reader 9.

Obvious workaround is using another browser, but the IE8/XP/Reader 9.4 configuration is prevalent in our environment, and users do not have admin rights to install alternative browsers themselves.  Due to other application dependencies, it would be a much simpler option to change Reader versions, if this happens to be the problem.

Has anyone else encountered this?  Any ideas which components might be causing this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I learned that this has to do with the zoom setting on IE8.  This problem occurs when the zoom is greater than 100%.  Solution is to change zoom setting, exit Workspace, then re-enter under new setting.

Hopefully someone else may find this helpful.

Comment: Thanks, I had the same issue.  Perfect fix!